# Is there any difference between using pip in CMD, Pycharm project terminal or installing packages through Pycharm interface?

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

Is there any difference between using pip install in CMD, using it in the Pycharm project terminal or installing packages through the interpreter settings of the Pycharm interface?

Answer (score 0):

There should be no difference assuming that you're talking about PyCharm using pip underneath, which it does by default.  The other big thing is to make sure that you're working on the same Python installation in each case.  You could certainly have things set up such that, by default, these different options are each addressing a different installation of Python if you have multiple versions of Python installed.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no difference, as long as your IDE is using the same installation. If that is the case, choose the option, that is the easiest for you.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're using the same environment / interpreter there should be no difference